# Try Catch cannot work with require_once in PHP?

Tags: php

I can't do something like this ?

```
try {
    require_once( '/includes/functions.php' );      
}
catch(Exception $e) {    
    echo "Message : " . $e->getMessage();
    echo "Code : " . $e->getCode();
}
```

No error is echoed, server returns 500.

Comment: Check your web server logs. There will most likely be a PHP error message there.

Comment: FYI, `require` will not throw an exception.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can do it with `include_once` or `file_exists`:

```
try {
    if (! @include_once( '/includes/functions.php' )) // @ - to suppress warnings, 
    // you can also use error_reporting function for the same purpose which may be a better option
        throw new Exception ('functions.php does not exist');
    // or 
    if (!file_exists('/includes/functions.php' ))
        throw new Exception ('functions.php does not exist');
    else
        require_once('/includes/functions.php' ); 
}
catch(Exception $e) {    
    echo "Message : " . $e->getMessage();
    echo "Code : " . $e->getCode();
}
```

Comment: Tried to edit to correct the spelling error of file_exists, but the system wouldn't let me ("Edits must be at least 6 characters"). D'oh!

Comment: Nice! But still one in the line: if (!file_exsists('/includes/functions.php' ))

Comment: @Johan : Thanks again. hopefully fixed everything :)

Answer (score 10):

As you can read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) : (emph mine)

> require() is identical to include()
>   except upon failure it will also
>   produce a **fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level
>   error**. In other words, it will halt
>   the script

This is about require, but that is equivalent to require_once(). This is not a catchable error.

By the way, you need to enter the absolute path, and I don't think this is right:

```
 require_once( '/includes/functions.php' );
```

You might want something like this

```
require_once( './includes/functions.php' );
```

Or, if you're calling this from a subdir or from a file that is included in different dirs, you might need something like

```
require_once( '/var/www/yourPath/includes/functions.php' );
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work, but it is a bit of a hack.

```
if(!@include_once("path/to/script.php")) {
    //Logic here
}
```