# Exception handling problems in php

Tags: php, exception

I was trying out PHP exceptions for my project. But it turns out that the exception is thrown successfully but not being caught successfully by the code I wrote.

**The code:**

```
 try{
    require_once(MASTER_PHP."/master_validation.php");
    require_once(MASTER_PHP."/master_user.php");
    require_once(MASTER_PHP."/master_db.php");  require_once(MASTER_PHP."/master_secure.php");
    require_once(MASTER_PHP."/master_ui.php");
    require_once(MASTER_PHP."/master_mail.php");
    require_once(MASTER_PHP."/master_filehandling.php");
    require_once(MASTER_PHP."/master_archive.php");
    require_once(MASTER_PHP."/master_date.php");
    require_once(MASTER_PHP."/master_social.php");
    require_once(MASTER_PHP."/master_message.php");
    require_once(MASTER_PHP."/master_gallery.php");
    require_once(MASTER_PHP."/master_backup.php");
    require_once(MASTER_PHP."/master_payment.php");
    require_once(MASTER_PHP."/master_sms.php");
    require_once(MASTER_PHP."/master_xml.php");

    $filterobj=new ta_filtervalue();
    $filterobj->filterrequest();

    global $noecho;
    if($noecho!="yes")
    {
        $utilityobj=new ta_utilitymaster();
        $utilityobj->includeextassets();
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $custerrcode=$e->getMessage();
$dbobj=new ta_dboperations();
$res=$dbobj->dbquery("SELECT * FROM ".ERROR_CODES." WHERE ".errordb_errcode."='$custerrcode' LIMIT 0,1",DB_ERROR);

$errmsg=$res[0][changesqlquote(errordb_errdesc,"")];
$errpriority=$res[0][changesqlquote(errordb_errpriority,"")];
$errcallback1=$res[0][changesqlquote(errordb_errcallback1,"")];
$errcalltext1=$res[0][changesqlquote(errordb_errcallbacktext1,"")];
$errcallback2=$res[0][changesqlquote(errordb_errcallback2,"")];
$errcalltext2=$res[0][changesqlquote(errordb_errcallbacktext2,"")];
$errtitle=$res[0][changesqlquote(errordb_errtitle,"")];

$errobj=new ta_errorhandle();
$errobj->senderror($errmsg,$custerrcode,$errpriority,$errcallback1,$errcalltext1,$errcallback2,$errcalltext2,$errtitle);
}
```

If the exception occurs in `master_user.php` (required file) it has to be caught in the file which requires it. But it does not catch the exception.

The way I throw the exception:

```
throw new Exception('#ta@0000000_0000000');
```

where the string inside is the error code.

The error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '#ta@0000000_0000000' in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\techahoy\securedir\phpmaster\master_user.php:19 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\techahoy\login\profile.php(4): ta_userinfo->userinit() #1 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\techahoy\securedir\phpmaster\master_user.php on line 19
```

Comment: So the program stops with an *uncaught exception* error?

Comment: sorry. just added the error message above along with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like (almost) the same as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369488/try-catch-cannot-work-with-require-once-in-php).

> require() is identical to include() except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. In other words, it will **halt** the script

Comment: after seeing your comment i tried changing all require i used to include but the same problem occurs.. is there any other way out?

Comment: Have you tried using an overall exception handler described in [set-exception-handler](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.set-exception-handler.php) ?

Comment: and just to add to the comment: to call a function within a class inside set_exception_handler, use: set_exception_handler(array('ta_errorhandle','exceptionhandler'));

where first string is class name and 2nd string is function name. Make sure that the function is static before doing this.

Comment: I don't really see how either answer apply; he's not dealing with an `E_COMPILE_ERROR` nor does he *need* to set a global exception handler. That exception *should* be caught as is.

Comment: @deceze: i am not sure. But using set_exception_handler works but using try catch blocks does not work. I am not sure why this problem is occuring.

Comment: @vignesh A global exception handler is just a last ditch rescue to *gracefully fail* on uncaught exceptions. It's not the same as using properly scoped `try..catch` blocks and gracefully catching the exception during regular program execution. I don't know why your scenario fails, but it's some problem in your code we can't see because we don't see the entire code.

Comment: yes. i do get your point but the tries fail even when i change require to include. in all the master files listed, i have functions within a class where i throw the exception as given above. that is all i do.