# php exception not catching

Tags: php, exception

I am trying to catch the exception, but couldnt, just am getting the error message

```
try{
    echo 'test';
    require_once "jj.php";
    return true;
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    throw new Exception("error occured");
}



 Warning: require_once(jj.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\corporate-wellness\module\Survey\src\Survey\Repository\QuestionRepository.php on line
```

Comment: Check out [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and trigger/throw your own error/exception.

Comment: duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369488/try-catch-cannot-work-with-require-once-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not an exception (but a warning), so you can't simply catch it.

You can suppress warning instead (not recommended in this scenario) or use something to verify if [file exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

So, something like

```
try {
    if(!file_exists("jj.php")) {
        throw new Exception("File doesn't exists");
    }
    require_once "jj.php";
    return true;
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    // if you would you can handle exception here or you can simply
    // throw exception without try - catch block
}
```

Comment: Is try/catch needed if you are already going to throw an error?

Comment: @Script47: you're right, you don't need it unless you would like to handle exception in a different way and not directly into if statement