# php require throw 503 status code

Tags: php, html, error-handling, require

I am using require functions as following:

```
<?php 
    require("../require/head.php"); 
    require("../require/header.php");
    require("content.php");
    require("../require/footer.php"); 
?>
```

Is it possible to throw 503 code if any require doesn't find its target and how?
Also is it possible to throw normal exception where I don't want 503 error and how?

Comment: I think this will not be easy with PHP because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369488/try-catch-cannot-work-with-require-once-in-php

Comment: You could try with include instead and send a 503 header if include fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the HTTP server response code is sent in the headers, you must determine this *before* any payload is sent to the client.

So you could either use output buffering or first loop over the required files checking readability, then use [`http_response_code`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) to send 503 if one of the resources are missing.

```
<?php

$files = [
    "../require/head.php",
    "../require/header.php",
    "content.php",
    "../require/footer.php",
];

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (!is_readable($file)) {
        // return 503
        http_response_code(503);
        die();

        // or you could throw an exception
        throw new Exception("Missing file: $file");
    }
}

foreach ($files as $file) {
    require $file;
}
```