# How to put proper error handling on include php file

Tags: php

I'm linking a php file but I want to be handle it when it errors and notify the user, is this the proper way of error handling of include? Or is it too long? What is the better way?

```
<?php
try{
if ((include 'File.php') == TRUE){
}
else{
  throw new Exception('Error loading the Parent Page: File.php ');
}
}
catch(Exception $e){
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage(). ' <a href = "sample.php">Return to HomePage</a>';
}
```

Comment: You should rather ensure the files you're including always exist. You should control that entirely.

Comment: Yes, but I want to error handle it too for some other instances.

Comment: What kind of instances? Anyway, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369488/try-catch-cannot-work-with-require-once-in-php) may help.

Comment: This would only throw an error if the included file is not available due to it being missing or an incorrect path. It won't report errors in the content of the file. Is the file hosted on another server or is it generated by another process? If not, PHP will throw an error anyway unless you have turned errors off which isn't a good idea.

Comment: Indeed, it depends if the goal is to check whether the file exists (which again, should almost never be needed), or if it's to catch errors that may occur when including said file. OP, you should clarify that a bit.

Comment: You should not use `include` or `require` or `require_one` for files that *might* be present. You should only use those on files that you *know* will be present at runtime. This kind of error handling isn't useful, and implies serious design/security flaws. For example, are you using this to include files that are in any way generated via user-input?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the if-statement and use `require_once('File.php');` inside your try-catch-block.

Now change your `Exception` to `Throwable` and it should work.

```
<?php
try{
    require_once('File.php');
} catch(Throwable $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage(). ' <a href = "sample.php">Return to HomePage</a>';
}
```

To check if the file exists, use:

```
if(file_exists('File.php')){
   require_once('File.php');
}else {
   echo "File not found";
}
```

Comment: This won't work until PHP 8. `require` / `require_once` do not throw exceptions/throwables.

Comment: What? I use this in my projects and it works fine on PHP 7.3.19.

Comment: Well [see for yourself](https://3v4l.org/mhrua). Maybe there's some PHP setting to alter that behavior, though I'd be surprised.

Comment: My guess is you're using a custom error handler that transforms those into `ErrorException`s. Though it should theoretically only work for `include`, not `require`, since it wouldn't catch fatal errors.

Comment: I think my method catches errors IN the file, so if the execution of the file returns a 500 error it will catch that, but if the file doesn't exist, it won't work.

Comment: I edited my answer and added a check if the file exists.

Answer (score -1):

It's good to use if-else block for checking whether you can include or require a file in the flow like this.

```
if( ! file_exists( 'File.php' )){
    echo 'File does not exist' . '<a href = "sample.php">Return to HomePage</a>';
}
else{
    require_once 'File.php';
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use throw/catch for local flow control like this! You can just move your error handling directly into the `if` statement.

Comment: okay I'm improving my answer by removing the try-catch block for this type of flow